# %% doesn't work but % does in library dependencies

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.6

I noticed that if I use `%%` then the library I want to download doesn't get downloaded but using only `%` works. Why?

`"org.mockito" %% "mockito-core" % "2.18.3" % "test"` doesn't work. I get error `sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.mockito#mockito-core_2.12;2.18.3: not found`

but `"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.18.3" % "test"` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because mockito is a java library. Use `%%` only when downloading scala library. `%%` is a shortcut, sbt replaces it with your project's scala version to the artifact name.